# Every cyclic subgroup of $F_n$ (the free group of rank n ) is separable

Tags: group-theory

wondering how does one show that every cyclic subgroup of $F_n$ (the free group of rank n ) is separable?

Comment: What do you mean by "separable (sub)group", @Jenny? It doesn't seem to be a regular, well-known term...

Comment: Sorry!  A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is separable if it is equal to the intersection of all finite index subgroups of $G$ containing it.

Comment: Hall proved that all finitely generated subgroups of finite rank free groups are separable. Stallings has a nice proof if this theorem in his 1983 Inventiones paper (unless I am misremembering).

Comment: Such groups are called cyclic separable groups.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of a theorem of Marshall Hall (1949):

*Every finitely-generated subgroup of $F_n$ is separable.*

As a topologist, I like the topological proof given by John Stallings, see Corollary 6.3 of

J.Stallings, "Topology of finite graphs", Inventiones Math., 71 (1983).